# Locating unmatched delimiters in Clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript, cljsbuild

Occasionally I find myself in a situation where I mismatch curly braces, parenthesis or square brackets: `{}()[]` in Clojurescript. I am using `leininingen` and `cljsbuild` I have a hard time tracking down the error source. Usually it boils down to something like this:

`Compiling "resources/public/js/whitespace.js" failed.
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unmatched delimiter: ) at line 1`

Followed by a extensive stack trace that does not seem to contain filename, line-number information.

How can I get more useful information?

**My workaround so far**

- use version control to look for differences of files and their previous states. Then see where brackets where changed.
- use vim's parens matching extensively `%` to the rescue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Paredit Mode to keep the S-expressions balanced while you type. In Emacs this Mode also warns you if you have an unmatched expression in a file.

There is a vim plugin that provides a Paredit Mode for vim, take a look here: https://github.com/vim-scripts/paredit.vim.

Comment: My Solution now is pretty much described here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10269/39064